# How to Reduce SVG Path for Web in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, logo, svg

I actually am trying to make a simple logo for my website and was thinking of using inline SVG for the logo. I made it with illustrator but the path code is too long, not like I see on other sites. On other sites, it is much small and compressed, but when I am outputting the SVG code it is too big.

I even tried the simply path option, it did not help.

This is the code and I could not figure out any way to reduce its SVG path size. Usually, most sites have a very compressed SVG path size while their logo contains more paths and anchor points.

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="224" height="32" viewBox="0 0 224 32"><path d="M11.21,8h.08a4.27,4.27,0,0,1,.94-1,2.11,2.11,0,0,1,1.28-.35h8.11q3.6,0,3.6,3a8.26,8.26,0,0,1-.27,2l-2.3,9.31c-.23,1-.39,1.76-.48,2.39A12.27,12.27,0,0,0,22,25H14.62a10.15,10.15,0,0,0,.7-1.69A24,24,0,0,0,16,20.89l2.45-10a2.2,2.2,0,0,0,.12-.62c0-.47-.31-.7-.92-.7H12a1.4,1.4,0,0,0-1,.29,2.06,2.06,0,0,0-.52,1L8,20.89c-.23,1-.39,1.76-.48,2.39A12.35,12.35,0,0,0,7.42,25H0a11,11,0,0,0,.71-1.69c.21-.65.44-1.47.67-2.46L5.47,4.15c.23-1,.4-1.76.5-2.39A11.2,11.2,0,0,0,6.12,0h7Z"/><path d="M23.61,32,24,28.67A6.7,6.7,0,0,0,25.5,29a21.54,21.54,0,0,0,2.4.11h8.57a2.05,2.05,0,0,0,1.37-.39,2.79,2.79,0,0,0,.73-1.48l1-4.15L39.53,23a4.87,4.87,0,0,1-1.15,1.57,2.29,2.29,0,0,1-1.49.47H28.81a3.72,3.72,0,0,1-2.54-.79,2.79,2.79,0,0,1-.9-2.23,5.74,5.74,0,0,1,.15-1.25L28.39,9a6.92,6.92,0,0,0,.19-1.68V7a2.88,2.88,0,0,1,0-.35h7.07L32.1,21.16a.41.41,0,0,1,0,.16v.12c0,.47.26.7.8.7h5.82a1.26,1.26,0,0,0,1.37-1L43,9a6.92,6.92,0,0,0,.19-1.68V7a3.39,3.39,0,0,1,0-.35h7.08L45.34,26.8a7.47,7.47,0,0,1-2.1,3.91A5.12,5.12,0,0,1,39.72,32Z"/><path d="M59.5,8.37h.08a4,4,0,0,1,1-1.25,2.11,2.11,0,0,1,1.32-.47h8.34q3.6,0,3.6,3a8.26,8.26,0,0,1-.27,2l-2.1,8.53a6.87,6.87,0,0,1-2,3.73A5.46,5.46,0,0,1,65.78,25h-8c-.59,0-1-.13-1.15-.39a2.82,2.82,0,0,1-.53-1.49h-.15l-1.15,4.69c-.23,1-.39,1.76-.48,2.39A12.35,12.35,0,0,0,54.14,32h-7l5.17-21.2c.23-1,.39-1.76.48-2.39a12.38,12.38,0,0,0,.13-1.76h6.66Zm.88,1.18a1.37,1.37,0,0,0-1,.29,2.06,2.06,0,0,0-.52,1l-2.41,9.94a2.26,2.26,0,0,0-.12.63c0,.47.32.7,1,.7h5.89a1.36,1.36,0,0,0,1-.29,2.28,2.28,0,0,0,.5-1l2.41-9.94a2.53,2.53,0,0,0,.11-.62c0-.47-.3-.7-.92-.7Z"/><path d="M81.7,17.53l-.81,3.28a2.6,2.6,0,0,0-.11.63c0,.47.32.7,1,.7h11.6a12.63,12.63,0,0,0,2.14-.23L94.17,25H77.72q-3.6,0-3.6-3a8.25,8.25,0,0,1,.27-1.95l2.1-8.53a6.9,6.9,0,0,1,2-3.74,5.51,5.51,0,0,1,3.69-1.19H94.67q3.58,0,3.59,3a8.75,8.75,0,0,1-.26,2l-1.46,6Zm8.87-2.9.92-3.76a2.2,2.2,0,0,0,.12-.62c0-.47-.31-.7-.92-.7H84.8a1.4,1.4,0,0,0-1,.29,2.06,2.06,0,0,0-.52,1l-.92,3.76Z"/><path d="M116.29,10.72c-.67-.13-1.28-.23-1.84-.29a23.44,23.44,0,0,0-2.6-.1h-2.53a1.24,1.24,0,0,0-1.38,1l-2.37,9.58c-.23,1-.39,1.76-.48,2.39A12.27,12.27,0,0,0,105,25H97.54a10.15,10.15,0,0,0,.7-1.69c.22-.65.44-1.47.67-2.46L101.4,10.8c.23-1,.39-1.76.48-2.39A12.38,12.38,0,0,0,102,6.65h6.39l-.19,2h.08a2.67,2.67,0,0,1,1.19-1.55,4.93,4.93,0,0,1,2.37-.45h5.43Z"/><path d="M137.1,20.93q-1,4.11-5.58,4.11H116.21l.27-3.17a6.54,6.54,0,0,0,1.59.35c.54.05,1.44.08,2.69.08h8.12a1.55,1.55,0,0,0,1.68-1.22l.27-1v-.16c0-.08,0-.13,0-.15,0-.6-.4-.9-1.19-.9h-8.46q-3.14,0-3.14-2.94a9.34,9.34,0,0,1,.27-2.07l.58-2.23q1.18-5,5.28-5h15.88l-.27,3.17a6.09,6.09,0,0,0-1.57-.35c-.56-.06-1.45-.08-2.68-.08h-8.42a1.33,1.33,0,0,0-1.45,1.09l-.23.86v.2a.54.54,0,0,0,0,.2c0,.47.32.7,1,.7h8.19c2.52,0,3.79.93,3.79,2.78a5.37,5.37,0,0,1-.2,1.33Z"/><path d="M147.05,20.89c-.23,1-.39,1.76-.48,2.39a12.27,12.27,0,0,0-.13,1.76H139a10.15,10.15,0,0,0,.7-1.69c.22-.65.44-1.47.67-2.46l4.1-16.74c.23-1,.39-1.76.49-2.39A10.18,10.18,0,0,0,145.14,0h7Z"/><path d="M157.73,17.53l-.81,3.28a2.6,2.6,0,0,0-.11.63c0,.47.32.7.95.7h11.6a12.63,12.63,0,0,0,2.14-.23L170.2,25H153.75q-3.6,0-3.6-3a8.25,8.25,0,0,1,.27-1.95l2.1-8.53a6.9,6.9,0,0,1,2-3.74,5.51,5.51,0,0,1,3.69-1.19H170.7q3.59,0,3.59,3a8.75,8.75,0,0,1-.26,2l-1.46,6Zm8.87-2.9.92-3.76a2.2,2.2,0,0,0,.12-.62c0-.47-.31-.7-.92-.7h-5.89a1.4,1.4,0,0,0-1,.29,2.06,2.06,0,0,0-.52,1l-.92,3.76Z"/><path d="M182.14,17.53l-.81,3.28a2.6,2.6,0,0,0-.11.63c0,.47.32.7,1,.7h11.59a12.53,12.53,0,0,0,2.14-.23L194.61,25H178.16q-3.6,0-3.6-3a8.25,8.25,0,0,1,.27-1.95l2.1-8.53a6.9,6.9,0,0,1,2-3.74,5.54,5.54,0,0,1,3.7-1.19h12.47q3.6,0,3.6,3a8.26,8.26,0,0,1-.27,2l-1.45,6Zm8.88-2.9.92-3.76a2.53,2.53,0,0,0,.11-.62c0-.47-.31-.7-.92-.7h-5.89a1.4,1.4,0,0,0-1,.29,2.06,2.06,0,0,0-.51,1l-.92,3.76Z"/><path d="M224,6.65a6.62,6.62,0,0,0-.63.33l-1.24.75q-.88.52-2.34,1.44c-1,.62-2.22,1.39-3.75,2.33l3.22,10.84a9.67,9.67,0,0,0,.55,1.27,14.28,14.28,0,0,0,.82,1.43h-7.8L210,15.53l-3.14,2L206,20.89c-.23,1-.39,1.76-.48,2.39A12.35,12.35,0,0,0,205.4,25H198a10.12,10.12,0,0,0,.71-1.69c.21-.65.44-1.47.67-2.46l4.09-16.74c.23-1,.4-1.76.5-2.39A11.2,11.2,0,0,0,204.1,0h7l-3.4,13.89L217,7.82a2.85,2.85,0,0,0,1.11-1.17Z"/></svg>
```

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately, you aren't giving us *anything* to work with. There's no blanket "reduce SVG code" command.. we need to see the SVG XML or the artwork, something.

Comment: @Scott just edited the question. Please check!

Comment: Dunno.. looks pretty clean to me. each glyph has a path element, 10 paths. Not sure how you could reduce it to fewer paths.

Comment: Is it fine to be used as inline SVG for logo on my website? The output code is too large. I was wishing if I could compress it a bit.

Comment: What do you mean "too large"? The SVG file is only 4kb.

Comment: I am using it on site as SVG code, not file.

Comment: 4kb is nothing. NO need to worry

Comment: It's only 4kb.. as a file or as inline code. I can't see how it's "too large". Unless you mean the string of xml is long... which really means nothing and you shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: I mean yeah your font is unoptimal, thats mainly because it has for bad quelity print features like ink traps and slightly undercut coners, that you really dont need in there.

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying won't work for this because Illustrator knows nothing about how to preserve the shapes of letters.

I'm not suggesting you do this, because 4kb for an SVG is not large anyway. The SVG you already have will work just fine as an inline SVG on a web page. I include the following solution only because it ***is*** possible to reduce the size further.

You could edit the paths manually to remove the redundant anchors between the curves, remove the [ink traps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9FTN.jpg), and manually readjust the Bézier curve handles. This would reduce the SVG size a little, but not by much, perhaps less than a third. It might not be worth the trouble to save perhaps just 1 kb though. You'd need to edit every letter manually.  Combining all the paths to a compound path will also help a little.

Here's an example with the letter P showing the anchors which could be removed (left), and the result (right).

[image]